# Wiener filter modeling

Tags: wiener-filter

What would happen if we changed the input with the output in the Wiener filter computations? When we are designing a filter we use the input and the desired response vectors to find the Wiener filter. But what would happen if we changed the input with the desired response (output)? Filter is not reciprocal so I can imagine what would happen.

Comment: They don’t necessarily have the same dimensions